# How can I catch error of Dictionary at initializing time?

Tags: swift

with this down code I would get error, because I am using same key twice, I want to know if my app or code end up to this kind of error, how can I catch the error? and stop crashing app.

```
    let randomDic = [
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
    "c": 3
]
```

Comment: I don't you get an error, or are referring to your business logic error? may be one solution is prevalidate with a dictionary extension

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to add the items iteratively and test for it manually.  At a simple level something like this:

```
if string[newKey] == nil {
  string[newKey] = newValue 
} else {
  //handle error
}
```

In reality it'd probably be more complex than that depending on the app logic behind it, but a better approach would be to design the app so that the situation can't occur in the first place.

I'd also suggest not using `string` as a variable name, especially for something that is a Dictionary not a String!

Comment: thanks for answering, you are preventing error to happen, you are not dealing with error, as I asked in question, in some how way my app end up to that error, if that error happens, my app is going crash, I want stop crashing the app with allowing the error happen also.

Comment: You can't - if you have a fatal error such as that your app will crash.  The only way you can prevent the crash is to catch the error before before it happens.  Either by the sort of defensive programming above (possibly consider using a failable initialiser), or by writing the app such that the situation never occurs through using better logic or a different data structure.  The latter is obviously the better approach.